# Why is '<<<' filtering null bytes in gdb where '<()' does not?

Tags: bash, gdb, stdin, named-pipes

I recently discovered that the `<<<` trick in `gdb` to feed the `stdin` of the debugged program is filtering the null bytes out from the stream.

Here is a small example (that anybody should be able to reproduce at home) to testify that it filters out the null bytes:

```
$> python -c 'print("A\x00" * 10)' | cat -A
A^@A^@A^@A^@A^@A^@A^@A^@A^@A^@$
$> gdb /bin/cat

... gdb license prelude ... snip...

(gdb) r -A <<< $(python -c 'print("A\x00" * 10)')
Starting program: /bin/cat -A <<< $(python -c 'print("A\x00" * 10)')
/bin/bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
AAAAAAAAAA$
[Inferior 1 (process 3798) exited normally]
```

Where, using the bash-specific `<()` [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) leave the null bytes reach the program `stdin` within `gdb`:

```
(gdb) r -A < <(python -c 'print("A\x00" * 10)')
Starting program: /bin/cat -A < <(python -c 'print("A\x00" * 10)')
A^@A^@A^@A^@A^@A^@A^@A^@A^@A^@$
[Inferior 1 (process 3804) exited normally]
```

So, I have always thought that `<<<` and `<()` were doing about the same thing which is now obviously wrong. I would like to know what are the differences between the two methods and have an explanation about the `bash` mysterious error message stating that:

```
/bin/bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

Any help is more than welcome!

Comment: For a start `<<<` adds a trailing new-line character at the end of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, I always though that `<<<` and `<()` were doing about the same thing which is now obviously wrong.

Those don't do *at all* the same thing.  The `<<<` operator *redirects* a "here string" to the associated process's standard input.  Process substitution via `<()` *expands to* the name of a file (generally a FIFO or similar) from which the standard output of the given command can be read.

What you seem to mean is that the combination of `<<<` with command substitution (via `$()` or backticks) does about the same thing as the combination of ordinary standard input redirection via `<` with process substitution.  *This* is true, but as you've discovered, the semantics are not exactly equivalent.

> I would like to know what are the differences between the two methods and have an explanation about the bash mysterious error message

The key difference is that redirecting from a here string requires first producing the string as a value held by the shell (which you're doing via a command substitution), whereas redirecting a process substitution involves the redirected output being read *directly* by the associated process.

Ultimately, the diagnostic you receive indicates that the unexpected behavior you experienced arises from the behavior of command substitution, not the behavior of `<<<`.  Although I don't find it explicitly documented, I am not at all surprised that Bash strips null characters from program output when it processes a command substitution, for I expect its internal representation of shell strings to be as C strings.  C strings are null-terminated, and therefore cannot represent character sequences that include the null character.

**Update:**

Note also that, as @sorontar observed in comments on the other answer, POSIX says that if the output of the command in a command substitution contains null bytes then the result is unspecified.  Bash is thus free to strip the null bytes -- or indeed to do more or less anything it wants when it sees them -- without sacrificing POSIX conformance.  Other shells may make different choices in this regard than Bash does.  This is an excellent reason to avoid command substitutions where a null byte appearing in the command's output is a foreseeable possibility.

Comment: Ah, I have been totally wrong for long! Thanks a lot for your explanations! It is really crystal clear now!

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, these two methods are not the same thing (though in some cases can be used for the same reason)

This `<<<` is a here string and is subject to variable expansion rules. Bash does not allow null bytes present at variable values.

On the other hand the process substitution `<()` is treated as a file and null characters are allowed in files.

So the differences you noticed are due to this bash behavior. 
With a different shell maybe this restriction is not valid.

More tests:

```
$ echo -en "A\x00A\x00A" |od -t x1c
0000000  41  00  41  00  41
          A  \0   A  \0   A
0000005

$ a=$(echo -en "A\x00A\x00A");echo "$a" |od -t x1c
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
0000000  41  41  41  0a
          A   A   A  \n
0000004


$ cat <(echo -en "A\x00A\x00A") |od -t x1c  #this is treated as file
0000000  41  00  41  00  41
          A  \0   A  \0   A
0000005
$ cat <<<$(echo -en "A\x00A\x00A") |od -t x1c  #this is considered a variable
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
0000000  41  41  41  0a
          A   A   A  \n
0000004
```

Comment: With respect to the behavior of different shells, it is relevant to note that the `<<<` operator is a Bash extension, not a standard feature of the POSIX shell.  On the other hand, it is entirely plausible that another shell indeed could accommodate strings containing null characters.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Try `zsh -c 'cat <<<$(echo -en "A\x00A\x00A") |od -t x1c'`. In fact, zsh allows `\0` bytes.

Comment: Furthermore @JohnBollinger [If the output contains any null bytes, the behavior is unspecified.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03). There is an **explicit "special exemption"** in "command substitution".